# asp.net mvc master details and routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to model class and sections of a class and further instances of sections.

so route should be 
Class/ (Create, Details, Index, Edit) for classes

Then I've a section controller

ClassSection

so I would do

Class/1/ClassSection/ (Create, ... ) since ClassSection without classid is useless

and then further

Class/1/ClassSection/1/Instance

to go to SectionInstance controller

how can I map my routes to conform to this notation

I've tried doing this for class sections

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      "ClassSections",
      "Class/{classid}/ClassSection/{action}/{id}",
      new { controller = "ClassSection" },
      new { classid = @"d+" }
  );
```

but I can't generate a proper link from Html.ActionLink in Index action of Class

Comment: What is wrong with the links it is generating?

Comment: i'm trying to use something like this 
<%= Html.ActionLink("List Sections", item.ClassID.ToString())%>
which generates a link like this 

http://localhost/Class/1
and says resource can not be found

wherease I want it to generate a link like this 
http://localhost/Class/1/ClassSection/Index
or route to that link

Comment: I did try with several variations but couldn't get it to work either, i'll try again..
something like this
<%= Html.RouteLink("List Sections", "ClassSections", new { classid = item.ClassID })%>
generates a blank
http://localhost/ URL

Comment: @SnapConfig: Given the hard constrains "Class" and "ClassSection" in your Url template, I doubt that you need `new { classid = @"d+" }` to make it a unique match.  Try removing that part of your MapRoute and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Also, check your route with Phil Haack's Route Debugger, and make sure you're getting matches correctly on the route.  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: wow Robert that really works removing new {classid =@"d+"} generated proper URL you can put it in answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using Areas.  It sounds like you're moving in this direction already, but ASP.NET MVC 2.0 has specific support for this.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/31/single-project-areas.aspx

Given the hard constrains "Class" and "ClassSection" in your Url template, I doubt that you need new { classid = @"d+" } to make it a unique match. Try removing that part of your MapRoute and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: add this moment I would like to stick with MVC 1.0, also I'm not quite sure how areas would help here since it would be top level separation instead of sub level separation that I want.

Comment: You say it's not generating a proper link.  Is it routing Urls properly?